# How to extract a number from a string?

Tags: excel, vba

```
abc = Sheets("02").Range("calc02").Value  // value is: Rabat 5%
xR = Mid(abc, 7, 1) // Result is: 5
```

This is ok, but what if the content is: Rabat 50%, or Rabat 100%
I want to extract this number only, whether it is one, two or three-digit.

Comment: Does your string always contain the numeric portion at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xR = Mid$(abc, 7)  ' Returns 5% or 50% etc
xR = Left$(xr, Len(xR)) - 1)  ' strips the %
```

or, if you want xR returned as a *number*

```
xR = Val(Mid$(abc, 7))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
var number = Regex.Match(abc, "[0-9]+");
```

Comment: But it could work with some syntax changes: http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
xR = Mid(abc, 7, Len(abc)-7)
```

Assuming the string is always the same, this takes the length of the string into consideration to dynamically return the value. This will only work with that format, but that sounds like what you want :)

If you instead wanted the percentage AND the word(s) in front were if variable length, this may work:

```
percent = Right(abc, InStr(StrReverse(abc)," ")-1)
xR = Mid(percent, 1, Len(percent)-1)
```